# Why didn't Gauss take the other orientation of the sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry

I was wandering if there is a reason for which Gauss decided to take the orientation of the sphere in the counterintuitive way (e.g.: if $p$ is a point of the unitary sphere, $N(p)=-p$ instead of $N(p)=p$). I guess there's some geometric intuition which becomes easier thinking that way. Does anyone have a suggestion for which one? That's the reason for that ugly "**minus** $dN(p)$" as well.

Comment: Where did Gauss do as you suggest? The reason for the "ugly" negative sign in the definition of the shape operator is so that it is computed in terms of the second fundamental form (which has the second derivatives of the parametrization) without additional negative signs.

Comment: I read that he took such an orientation of the sphere. So you argue that it's just a purely mathematical matter? It is true that a minus sign should not add or take so much to geometrical interpretation, so you are probably right.